# what is "synchronising point" in multi threading?

Tags: linux, multithreading, semaphore

I need to decide on how many counting semaphores needs to be used for one of the multi threaded application. I came to know, if we know synchronising points then we can decide the number of semaphores to be used. What are synchronising points?

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question quality.

Comment: In this case, a synchronize point is where any thread waits for a semaphore. Knowing the number of synchronization points may or may not help decide on the number of semaphores to be used, since a single semaphore could be used at multiple synchronize points, based on a "handshake" sequence between threads. Normally there is at least one semaphore per thread. You may also need something like mutex and condition variable when working with objects shared by threads, which is a bit awkward, but linux doesn't support something like Windows WaitForMultipleObjects().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A synchronization point is a place in the flow of execution where a thread must wait for other busy threads, so that the data they are working on is in a proper state to continue.

For instance, a process may have to way for a free slot in a buffer, while another thread is emptying the buffer.